# How best to air seal kitchen pantry ceiling

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency, energy-audit

We just moved in and had an energy audit done by a professional, and they flagged that we were losing a ton of air through the ceiling in our kitchen pantry/ closet. The ceiling itself is a weird hodgepodge of wood scraps, pipes, etc.

What is the best way to air seal this to improve efficiency?

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two choices for the large gaps:

1. Continue to piece-meal it with whatever scraps of lumber/plywood/OSB you may have laying around.
2. Remove the random bits stuck in there and cover it with a single sheet of plywood/OSB. This might involve adding some 2x4 or 2x6 blocking to attach the sheet goods to. Again, whatever you've got on hand, or whatever's cheap at the big-box store today. This isn't structural, you're just looking to stop air flow.

If you want/need insulation here, feel free to add fiberglass, rockwool, foam board or whatever other insulation is necessary to whatever R-value you need, then cover it up.

Once the big gaps are covered up, spray foam around all the corners, edges, and penetrations. If there are places where you couldn't get a tight fit and the gap is still a bit big for the spray foam, push backer rod in first and spray foam over that.

Use fire-block rated foam if there's space above this, such as additional living space or an attic, or if there are appliances nearby that could cause a fire (such as HVAC equipment or a dryer).

Comment: Looks like OP may have bigger openings than what could be filled with spray foam.

Comment: Agree with SteveSh; looking for some advice on the huge holes that are too big to fill in with spray foam.

Comment: Fair points, I embedded the images in the question, but hadn't had enough coffee yet to really look at them while I was embedding.

Comment: Thank you, FreeMan, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a piece of xps foam board and cut it to fit vertically above the closet door jamb header.

Add some scrap nailing edges for the vertical xps to sit against and either tack it onto the nailers or foam PL it to the nailers.  Cut the two holes for the abs and one for the 1/2" pex and then caulk or spray foam around the sides and penetrations depending on the size of the gaps.  Backer rod is a good idea as well.

Did your energy guy give you an ACH50 number?